# ssh-add not saving identity after reboot - continues to fail after editing config file and trying numerous flag options

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I have tried numerous options to add my ssh key for bitbucket to no avail.

When I reboot it `ssh-add -L` it says `The agent has no identities.`

I have tried using the following guides to add my ssh-key:

- https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
- https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

I have tried several configurations of my config file including the following:

From BitBucket docs

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes
```

From Github docs

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

I tried using `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/bitbucket` and `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/bitbucket`

I tried starting the agent 2 different ways

From BitBucket docs

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

From GitHub Docs

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

When I run it, it works until I reboot. Sometimes it doesn't work when I switch terminals or use git operations in VSCode.

On reboot nothing works.

Looking for any solutions

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from:

> ```
> --apple-use-keychain
> ```

that you're on macOS (I added that to the tags).  This matches up with another part of your question:

> Sometimes it doesn't work when I switch terminals ...

There are two tricky bits that intertwine here:

- It's possible to have more than one ssh-agent running (but generally you *don't* want this).
- On macOS, when you boot up the system and log in—even before any Terminal windows open up—the *system* has started one ssh agent for you.

This second bullet point is specific to macOS.  On other systems, it's usually the case that the system has *not* started an agent for you, and therefore you must start one.  But on macOS the system *has* started one for you.  You don't want to start a second one!  So *do not* run `` eval `ssh-agent` ``.

If you *do* run it, you get a second agent, as requested, and then *only that one Terminal window* can *talk* to that agent.  This results in other Terminal windows not working, as you observed, and could lead to other similar issues like the VSCode one, perhaps.  (I don't use VSCode so this part is just a guess.)

You *do* have to run:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

or similar at least once; I do it after each reboot, to load the key into the agent.  According to [this question on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48502), using `-K` will save the *passphrase* for the key, and on Sierra or later you must take an extra step as well; see that question and its answer for more.

(I switch OSes a lot so I tend to avoid depending too much on any one particular OS's features.  The trick with Terminal and ssh-agent is actually kind of annoying, in that respect.   But it is useful.)

Comment: Thanks for the details, makes more sense! Question: Is there a way you can make sure you don't have to load the ssh key in after each reboot and just have it load automatically for all terminals/applications?

Comment: See the apple.stackexchange.com link. I haven't used this method but it should work. (My understanding is that it saves your passphrase in the OSX keychains, and then loads the ssh key into the ssh agent it starts, using your OSX keychain data to cause that to happen, so that as long as you use the existing agent that's already running—by not running your own—you'll use an agent with the key pre-loaded.)